# Question about stack and local variables when calling methods

Tags: c#, arguments, stack

I'm learning C# from the book Head First C# and the following screenshot is taken from page 605. It's showing here what the stack looks like when calling methods.

As I understand from the book, when you call a method, its local variables will be stored on the stack temporarily until the method returns. Given the example in the book, I don't understand the following:

1. Why isn't `MealSize` added to the stack before `Capacity`?
2. Why are there 2 `Bowl dogBowl` on the stack? Shouldn't they be the same argument being passed?

Thank you so much for your help!!

[image]

Comment: The graphic got some details wrong, `Eat` needs `mealSize` and `dogBowl` but the example "stack" is showing `capacity` and `dogBowl`.  Possibly they build the stack for `FeedDog` -> `CheckBowl` -> `Eat` -> `WriteLine` instead of the actual call hierarchy.  Also, it mysteriously uses `Type paramName` for references but `paramName ` **`value`** for numeric parameters

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Ben! Really appreciate it! Yes, I've also noticed the weird `Type paramName` for references but `paramName` `value` for numeric parameters, as you mentioned. Do you have any idea about my 2nd question? Should there be 2 `Bowl dogBowl` on the stack?

Comment: It is correct to have 2 `Bowl dogBowl` on the stack because one is in the parameter list for `FeedDog` and the other is in the parameter list for `Eat`.  It would be clearer if the two names weren't the same.  Every function expects to find its own parameters on the top of the stack, it has no idea to look down lower at the parameters of other functions to find what it needs.

Comment: Got it! Thanks so much again for your help! Could I also ask, is it parameters or arguments that are on the stack?

Comment: Sorry, not well formulated. I meant, as I understand, what's on the stack is the arguments being passed plus the local variables inside the methods. Is that correct?

Comment: In the .NET abstract machine, there's separate storage for local variables.  On real computers, these get put onto the call stack also (you end up with stripes of different "color" in the call stack, parameters of function A, locals of function A, return address from A's call to B, parameters of function B, locals of function B, return address from B's call to C, parameters of function C, etc.

Comment: Don't forget that there are three stacks to think about: the .NET logical execution stack, which is organized into a stack of function calls, each of which has arguments and local variables, and each contains a stack of intermediate calculations (usually a single line of C#), the image is a compressed version of these two. There is also the physical stack in machine code, which is how the above is usually implemented. You don't actually *have* to implement it that way (although it's efficient to do so), you could do it on pen and paper, or an abacus if you like. Do not confuse these three.

Comment: @BenVoigt A better way of putting it is that a function *cannot* access the stack lower down. There is simply no mechanism in IL to do so. All data it needs *must* be accessible in arguments, local variables or static fields (note that `this` is a hidden first argument)

Comment: Thank you so much for the additional information and knowledge, Charlieface!!

Comment: @Charlieface: There certainly are two mechanisms which can access locations lower down the stack: the `ref` keyword and pointer arithmetic.  The code consuming a `ref` doesn't know where the variable accessed by reference is stored; in "safe" code there's no way to access locations farther down the stack *unless invited to do so by the function that owns that stripe of the stack*.  If `unsafe` code is allowed, pointer arithmetic can easily read and write anywhere in the stack.  And then there are diagnostic APIs which offer stack-walking and inspection of parameters and locals throughout.

Comment: @BenVoigt Pointer arithmetic doesn't really count: it only works in unsafe code on particular CPU architectures, and is certainly not something you would do across function boundaries without an exact reference. Same for diagnostic APIs: the mechanisms used are outside of normal functions (they use native C++). Re `ref`: *"unless invited to do so by the function that owns that stripe of the stack"* is exactly my point. The `ref` itself must be on the current function's frame, and is no different in that respect to a normal object reference. I think we agree, just a different way of putting it.